# Short question - number theory

Tags: number-theory

Given $a\mid b+c$ or $a\mid b-c$ can we say that if $a\not\mid b$ then $a\not\mid c$ as well?

Comment: Yep! Because if $a | c$ then $a | (b + c) - c$ would say $a | b$.

Comment: A general tip: if you get stuck using a particular notation you could always go back to the definition.  I.e. $a\mid b+c \iff \exists k\in \Bbb Z, ak=b+c$.  You don't want to do this all the time, of course, but it can be useful for those times when you can't figure it out otherwise.

Comment: Consider $an = b\pm c$. If $a\not\mid b$ and $a\mid c$, the left hand side is divisible by $a$ but the right hand side is not, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

More generally, for all fixed $t$, if $a \mid b+tc$ and $a \mid c$, then $a \mid b$.

Indeed, $b+tc=au$ and $c=av$ imply $b=a(u-tv)$.

Answer (score 0):

If $a| (b+ c)$ and  $a|c$ then $a|[(b+ c)- c]=b$ because there are integers $m,n$ with $(b+ c)=ma$ and $c=na$ so $b=(b+ c)- c= ma- na=a(m- n)$, and $m- n$ is an integer.

Similarly, if $a|(b-c)$ and $a|c$ then $a|[(b-c)+c]=b.$

Always use the definitions. $x|y$ is defined as: There exists an integer $n$ with $y=nx.$